# Помогите решить проблему с телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, webbrowser

Это код Телеграм бота, который получает поисковый запрос и открывает браузер с результатами поиска. По идее он должен сначала спрашивать через что искать(через ютуб или через яндекс), потом мы должны ввести поисковый запрос и должна открыться страничка с результатами поиска. Но после того как мы вводим запрос ничего не происходит.
Помогите пожалуйста

```
import telebot
import config
import webbrowser as wb
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, добро пожаловать в SearchBot!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def where_search(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item = types.KeyboardButton("YouTube")
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Yandex")
    markup.add(item, item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Где будем искать?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search(message):
    global ws
    ws = None
    if message.text == 'YouTube':
        ws = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="
    elif message.text == 'Yandex':
        ws = "https://yandex.ru/search/?text="

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search_information(message):
    wb.open(ws + message.text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Бот не может взаимодействовать с компьютером пользователя. Никак. Ты пытаешься открыть страницу в браузере на той машине, на которой запущен бот.